# Does Java read a single byte in big endian bit order?

Tags: java, byte, endianness

So we can talk about the endianness of both the bit and byte order.
When I read the next byte from FileInputStream, for example, I practically get an 8-bit signed integer, but I have no idea what is the bit order with which Java calculates the byte's integer value. Which comes first, the most significant or the least significant bit?

(sign bit, 2^6 ..... 2^0)
Or...
(2^0, ..... 2^6, sign bit)

Comment: The left most bit represents the sign, the right most bit is the least significant. 0x80 = -128, 0x40 = 64, 0x20 = 32, 0x10 = 16, 0x08 = 8, 0x04 = 4, 0x02 = 2, 0x01 = 1, 0x00 = 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Endianness only really applies when a unit is broken down into other units. So if you were transmitting a byte over a bit stream, you could observe whether the least significant bit was transmitted first or last.  And at that point we could say that the stream was little-endian or big-endian.

But within a byte-addressable machine, i.e., where the byte is the smallest unit of storage, there is no "endianness" within the byte.  No bit of the byte is "before" any other bit of the byte.

Note that another term for endianness is "byte order". The order of bytes within larger entities.

It is true we like to number bits (0 to 7, for an 8-bit byte) so we can talk about them, but this really does not define endianness, even though the numbering is often chosen to match the byte order of the machine; this is convention.

With respect to FileInputStream - according to its documentation, that transfers bytes: no part of the byte is sent before any other part, at least not as far as FileInputStream is concerned.  If the byte has to be sent bitwise over some interconnect (say, a SATA cable), then the decision about which bit goes first is a matter for the hardware.  The higher layer code is dealing in bytes (or even blocks).

Comment: But apart from that, the "numbering" of bits you are talking about exists practically, right? I mean, on the lower level. A file is an ordered sequence of bits divisible by 8 sitting on my computer, or not? Mathematically speaking, if I were to convert 8 bits to an integer, there would be 2 ways of calculating its value. One way where the exponent increases (from 0) along with the bit index, and the other way when the exponent (from 7) decreases as the bit index increases. Is not that right?

Comment: In the CPU: the integer value is 2^0 * least-sig-bit + 2^1 * next-sig-bit, etc. The meaning of the bits is a matter of electronics in the ALU. Whether we call the least-sig-bit "0" or "7" does not change the electronics.  I don't know "where" that bit is in physical space. On magnetic tape: the bits of a byte are likely written "across" the tape, so none can be said to be first. On a disk: I would guess that the bits are written serially but that's not exposed to users of the disk.  In what sense can you say a bit in a file is "first" that does not depend on the software you use to display it?

Comment: Basically all I wanted to make sure is that if I read the same byte on different operating systems with different programming languages, then the numeric value of the signed 8-bit integer and unsigned 8-bit integer will not be different. For example if I have a byte whose signed value is -128, and the unsigned value is +128 (for bit sequence 1000-0000) on one system in a particular programming language, then these values remain the same for any system and any programming language. It was not promising to read about different bit orderings and bit swappings.

Comment: Then you're ok: a byte is just a byte.  Actually, there is one proviso based on programming language, and that is whether your eight-bit unit is considered signed or unsigned. But regardless of that, it's still the same 8 bits.

Answer (score 0):

in `int` first bit is the sign, the rest is the value, the last bit is the least significant bit.

Comment: Thank you. So that could be called big endian bit order, or not?

Comment: the endianess is about byte order in a value, for x86 this is little endian, in java int it is also little endian, it means the least significant `byte` is at the end. It is not about bit order in a byte, but about the order of bytes.

Comment: Well, but in a single Java byte, which is the most significant bit then? What is the order of exponents inside a Java byte?

Comment: @PatrikNusszer in byte, the most siginficant bit is the 2^7 bit. `Byte` is `Byte`, unless you're reading it bit by bit from some stream, it is obvious which bit is which :)